# Como pegar o retorno de um POST enviado pelo Cliente (DataSnap REST)

Tags: delphi, web-service, rest, post

Tenho um WebService Server REST desenvolvido pela IDE `Embarcadero Delphi XE7`, preciso pegar o retorno do `POST` do cliente.

Criei o WebService à partir do DataSnap REST Application, ao criar o projeto ele vem com as seguintes classes `Form`, `ServerMethods` e `WebModule`. Tenho uma função especifica para quando o cliente acessa ela via Http com o método `POST`, ela deve pegar o **usuário** e **senha** enviados pelo cliente via `Body` com o tipo do `content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, o cliente não usa autenticação.

Só que o meu problema, é como eu posso pegar essas informações quando o cliente envia essas informações.

Comment: Tenho a resposta de como deve ser feito para funcionar no Delphi com DataSnap REST, que é totalmente diferente de como é usado em Java, como foi colocado na minha pergunta. Então se alguém poder reabri-la eu conseguirei postar a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Jefferson, votei para reabrir e sinalizei para os moderadores. Sugiro que você edite a questão para deixar bem claro que ela é a respeito de delphi, e não apenas ficar implícito por causa da tag. Sugiro colocar alguns trechos de código que possam orientar outras pessoas que queiram responder (além de você mesmo).

Comment: @VictorStafusa, ta certo, vou editar a pergunta e explicar melhor, a resposta já tenho pronta para postar, quero disponibilizar para ajudar o restante do fórum. Obrigado

Comment: @VictorStafusa, editei a pergunta, espero que eu tenha sido claro, qualquer sugestão me avise.

Comment: Na forma atual a pergunta não é clara ou é ampla demais, se for reaberta e não tiver um problema para ser resolvido, ela poderá ser fechada novamente. Na forma atual entende-se que a pergunta só quer uma dica de como fazer, então a duplicata cai bem. Se é mais específico e não só a dica serve, aí a pergunta não dá subsídios necessários para responder adequadamente. Cada um vai responder o que bem entende.

Comment: @bigown, mesmo eu especificando qual IDE estou usando, editei a pergunta novamente, mas não sei mais o que incluir na minha pergunta para melhor entendimento, o que eu realmente queria quando postei ela, era como pegar o retorno do POST do cliente, mas feito em Delphi usando o DataSnap REST.

Comment: Amigos, desculpem discordar.. mas está claro que a dúvida do @JeffersonRudolf é quanto ao `Delphi` (ao menos após a edição), mais especificamente `DataSnap` e não de `Java` conforme a outra pergunta. Enfim, não considero uma pergunta duplicada.

Comment: Jefferson e @Andrey - O que o bigown disse é que mesmo não sendo duplicata, essa pergunta ainda tem outros problemas, por ser ampla demais. Sugiro colocar mais detalhes sobre o código na pergunta.

Comment: @bigown, editei a pergunta, espero ter sido claro, tentei especificar o Max o que eu quero e como eu criei o projeto para chegar na minha dúvida. Abraços.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, entendo, editei a pergunta, tentei ser o mais especifico possível, apontando para qual ferramenta quero que seja esclarecido e como cheguei nessa dúvida. Abraços